# Center column size - resizes in debug, but can't find backend code

Tags: html, css, wordpress, multiple-columns

Stackexchnage.wordpress.com sent me here because they thought it better suited for SO.

I have a site [here](http://azeverything.com/).

On that site, you'll see three columns. The page width is correct. The left side of the page is correct, the right column is correct, but the middle column, as you can see is not doing well.

**When I debug in Chrome, and I change this line...**

`<div class="border-wrap  right  in-full border bottom">`

to this

`<div class="border-wrap  left  in-full border bottom">`

...then the center column resizes and the site looks the way it should. I've tried for a couple of days to figure out where this is in the style sheet, and I can't find it anywhere. I've also searched through header.php and can't find it there either.

I need some direction here. Not being able to fix this is very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Find `.side-wrap` class in your CSS and edit it like this:

```
.side-wrap {
    width: 205px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 75px 0 0; /*edit this line*/
    padding-top: 10px; /*REMOVE this line*/
    margin: -10px auto 0 auto;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: All that does is centers the column. I want it to fill up the column width, to 335px, which is the size of that top image. Does that make sense?

Comment: I see. The center and the right column are using the same class `.side-wrap` to define their width. So you'd need to rename the center column  to eg. `.side-wrap2` and change its width. Question is if that is possible, as you may be simply using the same kind of Wordpress module for both ...

Comment: Not really, sorry. Without seeing the back end code, it is just a guessing game now :)

Comment: Send me an email at jared@jpcsolutions.com and I'll set you up. I'm desperate.

Comment: Before that - have you tried to localize the template by searching for that class that we need to work with - `.side-wrap` ? 
Best way that normally works for me is to do a full text search in your code repository and see where that class is located. Sublime Text would be a great tool to do that search.